# What does the HiveWarehouseConnector executeUpdate() function return?

Tags: apache-spark, hive

I can't believe I have to ask this here but there seems to be no documentation on what the HWC actually does. All I can find is that it returns a boolean:

```
public boolean executeUpdate(String var1)
```

But what does that boolean actually mean? Is it a success / failure code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From here [github](https://github.com/hortonworks-spark/spark-llap/blob/26d164e62b45cfa1420d5d43cdef13d1d29bb877/src/main/scala/com/hortonworks/spark/sql/hive/llap/HS2JDBCWrapper.scala#L212),
It is used for executing statements directly from the spark Driver to HS2 over a JDBC connection.

The return type boolean indicates if the hive statement run via the JDBC connection succeed or failed.

It is useful for DDL statements like 'create table'